# Which one should I use to annotate equations? \tag or \text?

Tags: math-mode, code-review

I am still confused in selecting whether to use `\text` or `\tag` for annotating equations. Which one should I use? If it is about personal preference, what is the pros and cons between them?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\section*{With \textbackslash text}
\begin{align*}
v = u + at && \text{without $s$}\\
s = vt - \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 && \text{without $u$}\\
s = ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 && \text{without $v$}\\
s = \frac{v+u}{2}t && \text{without $a$}\\
v^2 = u^2 +2as && \text{without $t$}
\end{align*}


\section*{With \textbackslash tag}
\begin{gather}
v = u + at \tag*{without $s$}\\
s = vt - \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag*{without $u$}\\
s = ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 \tag*{without $v$}\\
s = \frac{v+u}{2}t \tag*{without $a$}\\
v^2 = u^2 +2as \tag*{without $t$}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\text`, in my opinion comments does not belong in the area where we normally find equations numbers. This will only end up confusing readers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\tag` is intended to be used a a one-off equation number as an alternative to just adding one to the last number used. In particular it becomes the default text for `\ref`. This gives some clues as to when to use one or the other. If the comment is essentially part of the equation as in your examples, use `\text` you will never want  `see equation \ref{foo}` to make

> see equation without t

On the other hand if the comment is a kind of label that you may want to reference, use `\tag`.